# a>b>c Evaluation When Each Has Numeric Values

Tags: c, expression, associativity

I came upon a competitive C question which goes as follows:

**Find the output of:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int a=5, b=10, c=5;
    int x;
    x = a>b>c;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler responds 0.

What my explanation is that perhaps this is a side effect of right to left evaluation. My guess is, first `b>c` is evaluated **(assuming its is pushed into the stack first, I am confused here as I do know >'s left to right associativity)**, which evaluates to true. The value of this true variable, which is a number > 0 (is unknown to us), to which `a > that_value` is evaluated, yielding the result. However I may be wrong!

Any pointers/insights on how the output is evaluated would be useful.
Thanks.

**EDIT:** I tested in a very old compiler that gave 1, it was a mistake on my part, rectified it.

Comment: Negative voter, please explain the reason of your negative vote? So I may rectify it!

Comment: i dont get the downvote either as this looks strange and interesting. However, "some compiler"? What compiler give what output?

Comment: I doubt you will find a compiler that answers anything other than 0. The language specification has always been clear about the left-to-right associativity of the `>` operator.

Comment: Is this question primarily about why one compiler gives a different result as another or why you get `0`? If it's about the latter, it's a duplicate to already existing questions.

Comment: @alk No I was confused with the part that doesn't C push expressions in stack and the evaluation internally should be right to left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C compiler reads the code from top to bottom, left to right. 
here,`a>b>c` => 5 > 10 > c => 0 > 5 (false is representated by 0) => 0

So, the answer should be 0 for most of the Compiler which follow this order of precedence

For more Detail on the  [Order of Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

Comment: +1, but it's not because the compiler reads the code from left to right, but because the associativity of `<` is left to right.

Comment: @YuHao I am confused with the part that doesn't C push expressions in stack and the evaluation internally should be right to left?

Comment: @YuHao that's right.  With other operators e.g. `+` the associativity is _right to left_

Comment: there are some operator which are operated from right to left like assignment operator x = 5 the 5 is taken from right and kept to the  left of the operater. Besides these sort of operator and some rare function all other on c are executed left to right.

Comment: @Debojyoti if `+` sign is executed right to left what will be the answer of 6+++x; let here x be 5 .

Answer (score 3):

For relational operators the associativity is left to right so always you should get 0. I wonder how you got 1 on some compiler.